# Cannot Permanently Disable Application Switcher in Compiz

Tags: compiz, configuration

In order to have the basic <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> behavior, I disable the `Application Switcher` in `compiz`.

This works fine. However, the changes are gone after reboot.

How can I make this setting persistent? I'm on a *Lenovo X240* with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: My problem has gone away... Don't know why.